# Unicode 'not perpendicular' symbol

Tags: javascript, html, math, unicode

According to this [source](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/bylanguage/mathchart.html#geo), we have a neat way to show parallel, not parallel and perpendicular symbols. What I'm looking for though, would be crossed perpendicular symbol, or 'not perpendicular' symbol. I know it's very rare, but usage can be easily justified from math point of view, hence my question.

But it seems like it's not within Unicode character [list](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Sm/list.htm).

How can I add the symbol and render it with HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: not a programming question.

Comment: Are you familiar with Tex? If so, you could try some tools to convert Tex to HTML.

Comment: How about U+27C2 (PERPENDICULAR) followed by U+0338 (COMBINING LONG SOLIDUS OVERLAY): ⟂̸

Or U+0337 (COMBINING SHORT SOLIDUS OVERLAY): ⟂̷

Comment: How is drawing something using Javascript not a programming question?!

Comment: @Biffen: Do you want to make that an answer? The Arial on my OS X does a poor job of displaying your combined glyphs, but with other fonts this works nicely, and it's exactly what I myself would have suggested.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using characters, not programming.

Comment: It may be a little off-topic, or for some it may not. I don't mind if you don't thing it's programming, but I would have never encountered this issue if I wasn't a programmer. Nevertheless SO is always helpful! Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Turning my comment into an answer.)

You can use Unicode's [combining characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character), e.g:

U+27C2 (PERPENDICULAR) followed by either

- U+0338 (COMBINING LONG SOLIDUS OVERLAY):

  **⟂̸**
- or U+0337 (COMBINING SHORT SOLIDUS OVERLAY):

  **⟂̷**

Or some other character that you find fitting.

Naturally this will only work with supportive fonts and proper renderers (i.e. browsers in this case), but then again font limitations can always cause problems, with or without combining characters.

Comment: According to Unicode Technical Report 25 (UTR #25), “If a negated operator lacking a precomposed form is needed, U+0338 COMBINING
LONG SOLIDUS OVERLAY or U+20D2 COMBINING VERTICAL LONG OVERLAY can be used to indicate negation.” So U+0337 is not mentioned.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Good to know. But I take it that's merely a recommendation, or suggestion even? U+20D2 doesn't look very good with U+27C2, and I just thought U+0337 looked better than U+0338.

Comment: Didn't know about combining characters at all. Thanks!